# Turning on the ssl breaks the website

Tags: php, html, css, ssl

I was trying to turn on the ssl in http://top-minecraft-servers.com but it breaks. All the relative url like /userdata etc which are used in the img tag or as href it points to http not https. 
For example

```
<a style="text-transform: uppercase;" id="vote" class="btn btn-default serv-vote-btn" <? echo $account_user_id ?>"  href="/vote">
```

is going to

`http://top-minecraft-servers.com/vote`

not

```
 https://top-minecraft-servers.com/vote
```

My question is how to do it easily while not hardcoding all the links because hardcoding all the links will be very problematic.

Please help
Thanks

Comment: I don't know, what generates your HTML, but that code must use relative URLS anywhere, then you have no problems at all. If you use hard coded links, you must change them....

Comment: you're using php, take a look into the `$_SERVER` variable.. http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: links are all relative like /userdata

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a base href tag in your document which is the problem:

```
<base href="http://top-minecraft-servers.com/">
```

You need to change that as well to https:

```
<base href="https://top-minecraft-servers.com/">
```

Or, simply just remove it altogether.  I'm not sure it's serving any purpose at all.

If you have a `base` tag present, it's `href` attribute is basically prepended to all relative links in the document, effectively making them all *absolute* links

See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base